# loadModel always return true

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I put the following code in `AppController` or `RecipesController` in order to see the return value of `loadModel`. According to the [loadModel API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-Controller.html#_loadModel), it should return true when single model found and instance created.

However, I both got `1` which I considered it as `true`, even though `safasfasfafafafas` doesn't exist.

```
$this->log($this->loadModel('safasfasfafafafas'));   // random string
$this->log($this->loadModel('Recipe'));  // exist in my model
```

I'm quite new on cakephp, may I know where I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs are incorrect, please refer to a more recent version and also look at the source code as even the most recent docs are not really correct (or let's say they are misleading).

- **http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Controller.html#_loadModel**
- **http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-Controller.html#717-746**

As can be seen, `loadModel()` will always return true, also `ClassRegistry::init()`, which is used to actually load the model, will make use of an instance of `AppModel` in case the actual requested model doesn't exist, so the exception will only be thrown in case even that class cannot be found.

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html#understanding-models**

Also note that the model won't try to access the table when it's being instantiated, so the possible missing table exception will only be thrown once you actually try to use the model, for example for querying records.

Comment: awesome. I'll be aware about the doc and will confirm with source code next time. so cool.